# How do I turn off maintain scroll position on specific pages?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I am using the following jQuery in my header.php file, which is remotely included in every page of my site:

```
function detectScrollbar()
{
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
window.name=document.body.scrollTop;
}
else
{
window.name=window.pageYOffset;
}
}
function doScroll()
{
if (window.name) window.scrollTo(0, window.name);
}
```

This code maintains the scroll position on page refresh. I would like to know how to turn it off on particular pages. If anyone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work.

Create something with a unique id that you don’t plan on using elsewhere on your site, so maybe the page name.

```
<body id=”myPageName”>
```

Then add the following to your jquery

```
if ($('#myPageName').length > 0){
//everything you want to run inside here.   
}
```